# MATLAB behaviour of struct containing strings and cells

Tags: string, matlab, struct, cell

I would like to have a struct containing strings and a cell array of strings.

This works as expected:

```
x = struct('field1','one','field2','two');
>> x.field1
ans =    
one
```

but as soon as I have a cell array of strings, this is the output for `x.field1`:

```
x = struct('field1','one','field2',{'two','three'});
>> x.field1    
ans =    
one
ans =    
one
```

Can you tell me how to properly combine strings and cell arrays into a single struct? Thanks!

Comment: I've tried it with Octave, and such a definition seems to lead to a 1x2 struct array, with 'one' as value for both the entries related to field1. It's different if you define x as follow: `x = struct('field1','one','field2',struct('subfield1','two','subfield2','three'));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add two curly braces around the cell array to prevent Matlab from distributing its contents into a struct array:

```
>>x = struct('field1','one','field2',{{'two','three'}})
x = 
    field1: 'one'
    field2: {'two'  'three'}
```